# Approximating simple function by continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to solve this problem:

If $\gamma$ is a simple function defined on $E \subset \mathbb R^d$, $E$ measurable, then there is $f:E \to \mathbb R$ continuous such that $$|\{x \in E: f(x) \neq \mathcal \gamma(x)\}|<\epsilon$$

By definition, $\gamma$ is a finite linear combination of characteristic functions, $$\gamma=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \mathcal X_{E_i}, \space (c_i \neq 0)$$

where $E=\bigcup E_i$, $E_i$ is measurable and they are pairwise disjoint.

I could prove this ([Characteristic function approximated by continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250791/characteristic-function-approximated-by-continuous-function)):

Let $E\subset \mathbb R^d$ be measurable and let $ϵ>0$. If $A \subset E$ is measurable, then there is $f:E→\mathbb R$ continuous such that
$$|\{x∈E:f(x)≠\mathcal X_A(x)\}|<ϵ$$

and I suspect I must use this result to show the other statement, but I don't know how to.

Here's the answer after Wong's suggestion:

For each $E_i$, there exists $f_j:E \to \mathbb R$ such that $|\{x∈E:f_j(x)≠\mathcal X_{E_j}(x)\}|<\dfrac{ϵ}{n}$. I define $f=\sum_{j=1}^n c_jf_j$, this funcion is continuous on $E$ since it is a sum of continuous functions.

Then, if $S=\{x∈E:f(x)≠\mathcal X_{E_j}(x)\}$, for $x \in S$ we have $$0<|f(x)-\gamma(x)|$$$$=|\sum_{j=1}^n c_jf_j-\sum_{j=1}^n c_j \mathcal X_{E_j}|$$$$=|c_j||\sum_{j=1}^nf_j-\mathcal X_{E_j}|$$$$\leq |c_j|(\sum_{j=1}^n|f_j-\mathcal X_{E_j}|)$$

So at least there exists some $j$ for which $0<|f_j-\mathcal X_{E_j}|$. In other words, $$S \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^n \{x∈E:f_j(x)≠\mathcal X_{E_j}(x)\}$$

Note that since $S=\{x: f(x)-\gamma(x)>0\} \cap E$, then $S$ is measurable and $$|S| \leq \sum_{j=1}^n |\{x∈E:f_j(x)≠\mathcal X_{E_j}(x)\}|<\epsilon$$

Comment: You're on the right track. Using the result you proved, you know how to approximate each characteristic function. The function you want to approximate is a sum of characteristic functions, so you can approximate *that* by...

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll write my solution in a couple of minutes. If you feel like, you can check if my solution is correct and you can put your comment as an answer since your hint helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: This looks fine. Make sure to put absolute values in your definition of $S$ in the second to last line.